# Escaping "import" and react/html to display as text in MDX?

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I am just starting with MDX inside of gatsby/react and I want to be able to escape things to display as normal text i.e.

For example, I want to display this as a standard text?

```
here is some info

 import {test} from "test"

ffdg

<text>dddd</text>
```

The import line complains in the playground (https://mdxjs.com/playground/) but if I start it with space it seems fine

but the line that starts with HTML angular brackets, space doesn't help. I have surrounded it with ticks but then its rendered with a grey background.

What is the correct way of escaping or telling MDX to ignore certain content?

Does anybody know

Comment: Have you tried to place it between `<code>` tag? Like this:

``<code>import {test} from "test"</code>``

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap everything with ```

````
```
here is some info

import {test} from "test"

ffdg

<text>dddd</text>
```
````

Answer (score 0):

If it's a code block, three back ticks solution is best, but if you want to escape the regular word "import", it's enough to HTML-encode its first letter "i", `&#x69;`:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From [here](https://mdxjs.com/docs/troubleshooting-mdx/#:%7E:text=If%20you%20want%20the%20word%20import%20or%20export%2C%20make%20sure%20it%E2%80%99s%20not%20at%20the%20start%20of%20a%20paragraph.):

> If you want the word import or export, make sure it’s not at the start of a paragraph.

Turns out  `import` (starting with a space) is just enough, and then HTML won't render that space.